# having trouble rendering dynamic data from an axios get request, dependent on select item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display data from my database, I am using an Axios request with parameters from a dynamical select tag, the request is sent and recieved but my custom display component doesn't update with the information.

I have a working one with similar code, which is why I am struggling to understand why this one doesn't work.

The Axios request updates the state, which should trigger the re-render, as you can see i have put for updates and this.render() there to force this incase it was a glitch occurring.

Can anyone please point out the newbie mistake please.

```
searchByRef(refNum){
    axios.get("http://"+Constants.api+"/IndividualProject/api/game/getAGame/"+ refNum).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                data: response.data
            });
            console.log("Request Sent")

    });
    console.log(this.state.data);
    this.render();
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.searchByRef(event.target.value);
}
```

dynamically sets the select tag from a previous request

```
getRefs() {
    let optRefs = [];
    let dataRefs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.games.length; i++) {
        dataRefs.push(this.state.games[i].reference);
    }
    dataRefs = dataRefs.unique();
    for (let j = 0; j < dataRefs.length; j++) {
        optRefs.push(<option value={dataRefs[j]}>{dataRefs[j]}</option>)
    }
    return <select id="refNum" name="refs" onChange={this.handleChange}>{optRefs}</select>;
}
```

Render method

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="search">
            <div id="searchCriteria">
                <div>Select Reference</div>{this.getRefs()}
            </div>
            <div id="searchContent">
                <GameDisplay data={this.state.data}/>
            </div>
         </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: maybe this.render() finish executing before axios receive data, try putting this.render() directly after    this.setState({ data: response.data
            });

Answer (score 1):

Since axios is a async call beacuse of which this.render() method is called before completion of axios call. You should use

```
axios.get("http://"+Constants.api+"/IndividualProject/api/game/getAGame/"+ refNum).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                data: response.data
            });
            this.render();
            console.log("Request Sent")

    });
```

Comment: I agree it is in the wrong place but the this.render() should be irrelevant though as the state is changed from the Axios response which triggerrs a render ?

Comment: Can you share your code ? So that i could go through it more deeply